# Style one specific Vuetify scoped component using class names

Tags: class, sass, scope, styles, vuetify.js

I need to add some scoped style to this Vuetify `v-text-field` component.

```
<v-col cols="5">
  <v-row no-gutters class="flex-nowrap">
    <v-col>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="textFilter"
        data-test-id="search-field"
        placeholder="'Search by account name'"
      >
        <template slot="append" class="searchButtons">
          <v-btn
           type="submit"
           data-test-id="search"
           @click="updateFilter"
           >
             Search
           </v-btn>
        </template>
      </v-text-field>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-col>
```

So I inspected the element, I found the Vuetify class name and scoped the style I need like this:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  ::v-deep .v-text-field > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot {
    padding-left: 8px !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
  }
</style>
```

The problem is that I have a few other Vuetify components in the same scope that use the same class names, and of course they are also being affected by that style above.

I tried adding an additional class to my component (e.g. `class="search-field"`), and to use it in the style selector (e.g. `::v-deep .search-field > .v-text-field > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot` ), but it doesn't work (I guess it's because these classes are not exposed but generated by Vuetify).

How can I select and style only that specific component?

Thanks

Comment: Probably you are doing something wrong with the css selector order. You are looking for an element with "search-field" class and you are looking for another element "v-text-field" which must be the child of the other element. But most probably search-field and v-text-field classes are on the same element.  You may want to check this first.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in the end, by adding an `id` to the highest node and then selecting like this:

TEMPLATE:

```
<v-text-field
   id="search-field"
   v-model="textFilter"
   data-test-id="search-field"
   placeholder="'Search by account name'"
 > ...
```

STYLE tag:

```
::v-deep #search-field > .v-text-field > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot {
  ...style
}
```